# Java says mail has been sent, But it actually has not

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a mail through java and it doesn't work. That also doesn't showany error. I am new to javamail so please help:) I searched this question everywhere but I could only find this problem in php. so please let me know how to debug this in java.

```
public void sendMail(){

        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String user = "tharumudu@gmail.com";
        String password = "pass";
        String to = "tharumudu@gmail.com";
        String from = "tharumudu@gmail.com";
        String subject = "Subject";
        String messageText = "Thada ! ";
        boolean sessionBug = false;

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required","true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
        session.setDebug(sessionBug);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress address = new InternetAddress(to);
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setText(messageText);


            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, user, password);
            transport.close();
            System.out.println("email sent successfully");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }


    }
```

I have call the method here

```
  public void sendButtonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        sendMail();
    }
```

Comment: Just because you print some sort of success message does not actually mean that email has been send successfully. You are missing a call to `send` here.

Comment: Please tell me how to call it @Glains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to either call `send` or `sendMessage` to send your email. So your following code

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, user, password);
transport.close();
```

can be replaced with

```
Transport.send(msg);
```

The username and password are already provided through your session properties.

Comment: @T.J Crowder has already given an anser to this question, but the OP requested an example.

Comment: Nice, glad you got it working. Please consider marking either T.JCrowders or my anser as accepted.

Comment: The above code is wrong.  You should use the [sendMessage](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#sendMessage-javax.mail.Message-javax.mail.Address:A-) method, e.g., `transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());`, or replace all of the above code with a call to the static [Transport.send](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method, e.g., `Transport.send(msg, user, password);`.

Comment: @BillShannon What makes you think that? [`send`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-) should work as intended.

Comment: send is a static method.  There's no point in calling it on an instance variable since it ignores the instance variable.  See the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#send).

Comment: @BillShannon Strange, i must have missed that. Guess i read over the documentation too fast, thanks a lot for your point!

Answer (score 3):

There's no call to [`send`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-) or [`sendMessage`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#sendMessage-javax.mail.Message-javax.mail.Address:A-) in your code. `send` is what actually sends the email. All you've done is create a message and connect. After connecting, send.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to call it? @T.J Crowder